# Substituting values using SymPy for initial conditions of odeint if they are present

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, enthought, sympy

I'm trying to solve a set of coupled ODE's using odeint in python; I initially created the program to solve 3 specified equations (where I use sympy.subs for each value I knew was present), but now I wish to solve N many coupled ODE's. The issue I am running into is how to properly substitute for initial conditions given a these equations were I *don't* know which values are present (i.e. which ones must be substituted).

For example: For an input of a 3x3 matrix, the set of ODEs I have is:

```
v0' = -6*v1*v3 - 12*v2*v6
v1' = -3*v1*(6 + v4) - 9*v2*v7 + 3*(3 + v0)*v1
v2' = -6*v2*(9 + v8) + 6*(3 + v0)*v2
v3' = 3*v3*(3 + v0) - 9*v5*v6 - 3*(6 + v4)*v3
v4' = 6*v3*v1 - 6*v5*v7
v5' = 9*v3*v2 - 3*v5*(9 + v8) + 3*(6 + v4)*v5
v6' = 6*v6*(3 + v0) - 6*(9 + v8)*v6
v7' = 9*v6*v1 + 3*v7*(6 + v4) - 3*(9 + v8)*v7
v8' = 12*v6*v2 + 6*v7*v5
```

where I have initial values for v0-v8 (where v0-v8 are set up as symbols through SymPy) in a vector but without manually substituting in each value, I don't know how to solve this.

Is there a way to substitute the values for v0-v8 without knowing which values of v0-v8 are present. (For different size matrices, the amount of initial values also change - i.e. 4x4 has v0-v15)

Edit: edited so that v0'-v8' are shown as functions of the coupled ODEs. When entering them in the odeint though, the equations are just implicitly equal to v0'-v8' by their position in the vector.

v0-v8 are created by:

```
v = sy.symbols('v0:%d'%matSize, commutative=False)
```

where matSize is an input int that correlates to the size of the input matrix.

Comment: Are `v0-v8` all functions of the same independent variable?

Comment: I don't understand fully what you're asking, sorry. v0'-v8' are functions of the equations above (implicitly), I'll edit the post above to show them as equations.

Comment: Can you post code that defines v0-v8 as sympy symbols?

Comment: @silvado I edited it into the bottom of the post.

Comment: It is quite unclear what are you asking about. What does this mean for instance: `Is there a way to substitute the values for v0-v8 without knowing which values of v0-v8 are present`? Additionally, it is quite unclear how are you mixing `scipy.odeint` and `sympy`. Finally, why do you use `commutative=False`?

Comment: My apologies, I had trouble initially figuring out how to properly word this - I ended up making it quite confusing. 

Basically - I need to substitute the values of all v0 through the total amount of them with initial values in scipy.odeint to solve the ODEs. My dilemma is that I do not want to manually substitute each symbol for it's value, I wish to automate this so that it works for any size input matrix. 

I am using commutative=False because the symbols are all matrix operators used by commutators, thus they need to not be commutative.

Comment: Are you looking for a symbolic or a numerical solution of the ODEs? And maybe we can follow your approach better if you post code for a working example (like the 3 ODEs that you wrote you started with).

Comment: Numerical. And I believe I found a (granted slow) side step to my problem. I just set a nested loop up that iterative sympy.subs for each symbol in each each equations, thus replacing all symbols.